# Handling presentation logic in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

The description below is heavily simplified - it's only one part of a bigger problem that we are tackling but the innards can be safely left out for this question.

Suppose we have the following models: -

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=2)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='AssignedItem')

class AssignedItem(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=2)
```

So basically a person may be assigned zero, one, or more items and each assigned item's value may be overridden for a particular person by specifying the new value in the `through` model.

What we are aiming to achieve is an html table which has **all** the `Item.name` as its header row, with one extra column in that header row for `Person.name`.

Each `Person` may have a different set of `Person.items` assigned to them so it is expected that if a `Person` has not been assigned an `Item`, the corresponding cell for that `Person` will be blank (***please see attached image***).

[image]

The question is how to place the correct AssignedItem value in the corresponding column. We have a Queryset of Items that we are looping over in the template to create the header row, and then we have a list of lists containing each person's items. But how do we ensure that the correct AssignedItem is displayed under the corresponding Item header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the main issue was to ensure that the correct `AssignedItem` is displayed under the corresponding `Item` header.

I tried a lot of things in the template, but it did not offer too much room to maneuver. I ultimately created the "table" in the view then passed the string to the template for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are constructing the list in the view,

> We have a Queryset of Items that we
>   are looping over in the template to
>   create the header row, and then we
>   have a list of lists containing each
>   person's items.

When constructing this list, make the list an ordered list, where if a particular value exists, assign it and if it doesnt, then insert None.
ie, the list for Jake should look like `[78, 45, None, 94, 72]`

Edit:
Since reordering is an issue, use a dictionary with the item as index
ie, the values for Jake should look like `{'Item1':78, 'Item2':45, 'Item4':94, 'Item5':72}`

Comment: That is one way to go about it. But like I said, this is part of a bigger process and changing the order pre-process or post-process does not suit the situation. But yes, we will try this out, see if can rearrange and items post-process without gravely affecting the code that follows.

Comment: or instead of reordering, use a dictionary instead of the list, with the item as index. If a value exists in the dictionary, print the value, else display None. So the Jake values would become: {'Item1':78, 'Item2':45, 'Item4':94, 'Item5':72}